# Using yo to update a Yeoman generator initially installed from a GIT url

Tags: yeoman

My generator is not in NPM registry. I install it running:

```
npm install -g git://domain.com/scope/generator-foo.git
```

Now I would like to update it using `yo` with the **Update your generator** menu item, but I get the following error:

```
yo
? 'Allo Yves! What would you like to do? Update your generators
? Generators to update: @scope/generator-foo
npm ERR! Darwin 14.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/yves/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.6/bin/node" "/Users/yves/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.6/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "@scope/generator-foo"
npm ERR! node v0.12.6
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Not found : @scope/generator-foo
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 '@scope/generator-foo' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Yep, `'@scope/generator-foo' is not in the npm registry.`, and no I don't want to publish it on NPM :)

Is there a way to configure my generator so Yeoman can update it with it's git url instead of the package name?

I know I can update my generator manually using `npm install git://` but I want to be able to `yo`

Answer (score -1):

You could publish it to the npm registry. Or like you said, update it manually. By the way, to update, its `npm up -g generator-foo`

Comment: The question is about updating within `yo`, **without publishing on NPM** and with a git url...

Comment: Then the answer is that is not supported yet (if ever).